# Rufus stuck on same method, creating file system

Tags: windows-7, rufus

I tried to install 64-bit windows 7 enterprise k on 16GB usb , but I had cancelled it and repluged.
I tried to make my usb formatting, but now it has stuck on “creating file system… (1/12 completed)”, I am so annoying.
Before this accident, it just takes few seconds to pass that “creating file system”, now it is taking almost 10 minutes and don’t let me go to next level…somebody help me

Comment: `I had cancelled it and repluged` ... how is that an accident? ... it sounds deliberate to me

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> in Rufus to zero the drive.

Let it run for a couple minutes and then cancel it.

Then try formatting the drive again.

If that doesn't work, you probably want to run a bad blocks check, which you can find in Rufus under the *advanced format options* (click on the down arrow to show these options).